# How to compress or scale down an existing DataTemplate in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Does anyone know if I can scale down an existing DataTemplate? In other words, if I have a DataTemplate that displays a group of text-blocks, and images at a size of 300 by 300, can I scale down that DataTemplate to 50x50 to create a view without modifying the DataTemplate itself?

I have several DataTemplates for different elements that are displayed in the diagram. I would like to do a scale down (Preview) of these DataTemplate in order to display it to the user as a list or a group of them.

At the moment my only choice would be to scale it down manually to the preview size, but I was wondering if there is a function I can use to scale it down automatically.

Thanks in advance.

```
      <DataTemplate x:Key="sElementLA">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=Data.Held, Converter={StaticResource heldConverter}}"
                Background="Transparent" x:Name="ElementIcon"
                Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
                TouchDown="touchDownHandler" TouchUp="touchUpHandler"
                TouchMove ="touchMoveHandler" TouchLeave="touchLeaveHandler"
                Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False"
                go:Node.Movable="False"
                go:Node.Location="{Binding Path=Data.Location, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                go:Node.LocationSpot="TopLeft"
                go:Part.SelectionAdorned="True"
                go:Part.SelectionElementName="ElementIcon"
                go:Part.SelectionAdornmentTemplate="{StaticResource NodeSelectionAdornmentTemplate}"
                go:Part.Resizable="False"
                go:Part.ResizeElementName="ElementIcon"
                go:Part.ResizeAdornmentTemplate="{StaticResource NodeResizeAdornmentTemplate}"
                go:Node.RotationAngle="{Binding Path=Data.Angle, Mode=TwoWay}"
                go:Part.Rotatable="False"
                go:Part.DragOverSnapEnabled="True"
                go:Part.DragOverSnapCellSpot="TopLeft"
                go:Part.RotateAdornmentTemplate="{StaticResource NodeRotateAdornmentTemplate}">
            <!--Element info-->
            <Grid ShowGridLines="False" Margin="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="300" Height="100" RadiusX="12" RadiusY="12" 
                               StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#5075ba" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" 
                               StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Fill="#bcc5d2"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="30,0,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Comapany Inspira Medium" 
                               FontSize="16px" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Comapany Inspira Regular"
                               FontSize="15px" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Comapany Inspira Regular" 
                               FontSize="15px" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <!--Element Node and Icon I-->
                <Grid ShowGridLines="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <go:SpotPanel MouseEnter="Node_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Node_MouseLeave" Grid.Column="0" >
                        <go:NodePanel Sizing="Fixed" go:SpotPanel.Main="True" >
                            <Rectangle Width="85" Height="85" x:Name="CB_VIcon" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="0"
                                Cursor="Hand" Fill="{StaticResource CB_V}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            </Rectangle>
                        </go:NodePanel>
                    </go:SpotPanel>
                    <Grid ShowGridLines="False" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,4,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="CLD" Margin="0,22,4,0" Foreground="DarkGreen" FontSize="16" 
                                       TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontFamily="Comapany Inspira Medium" Height="Auto" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <fa:ImaComapanyAwesome Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Icon="InfoCircle" Height="30"  
                                         Foreground="#33cccc" Margin="0,0,4,-10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: WPF has a multitude of scaling/transformation features, a number of which could easily address your question. Have you tried anything? Did you even research this question at all? Please explain what you've already tried, providing a good [mcve] that shows what _specifically_ you are having trouble getting to work.

Comment: @PeterDuniho i finally started working on this problem again, I have posted a better explanation of what I am trying to do and what I have done. Please let me know what do you think. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848195/how-to-reference-an-existing-datatemplate-in-a-viewbox

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be wrap the template's container in a `Viewbox`. `Viewbox` will scale its contents to fit itself.

Since `DataTemplate` is usually used in an `ItemsControl` you may need to use a custom container to utilize a viewbox around the template.

Comment: I came back to this problem this week. What kind of custom container do you recommend? I've tried to put a Rectangle class under the ViewBox, and under the Fill property I entered under the StaticResource the key name of the DataTemplate I want to resize, but it does not work.

Comment: @JC203 Sorry; I mean you would put the `Viewbox` in a custom `ItemContainerTemplate` That Fill thing is way wrong

Comment: But I still need to reference to the other DataTemplate under the ViewBox. https://blog.udemy.com/wpf-viewbox/ In these examples they have a button being resized. I want the button to be the datatemplate, and that is where I am struggling with.

Comment: @JC203 You set the `ItemContainerTemplate` to the thing with your Viewbox and the `ItemTemplate` to your DataTemplate; not sure what I'm missing here

Comment: I posted my question in a more concise manner since I believe this original question here is a bit confusing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848195/how-to-reference-an-existing-datatemplate-in-a-viewbox